# Drawing HERE Data on to ESRI JS Map

Tags: here-api

I am currently investigating the possibility of utilising the HERE APIs as source data inputs into possible solutions we would like to develop as a company on ESRI.

I understand that any data we retrieve from the API, i would need to create ESRI objects on the fly, and add them to an ESRI map layer.

However, one thing that is not clear in my mind, is how to calculate the tiles for my particular map extent.

The REST API specifies some base information, regarding calculating tiles based on lat lon - but what is the lat/lon of? is the map center? is it the bottom left or bottom right?

Are there any JS helper methods that HERE have, that would calculate the tiles required for a particular extent?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? Just visit the SO Help Center regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It increases the chance to get an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to this documentation part: https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/common/map_tile/topics/mercator-projection.html ?

It is the coordinate of the part of the map which you want to display e.g. the center of your map view.